# Edits needing fewer than 6 characters

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I always get an error when trying to edit posts with an edit of fewer than 6 characters.

So, how can we suggest an edit that is fewer than 6 characters?

Some posts are really good, but they only fail to use code tags or back ticks for a set of commands or log. For those posts, I just want to add the code tags or back ticks, but the 6 characters limit conflicts with this. What is the solution?

Comment: From Meta Stack Exchange: [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: “Edits must be at least 6 characters”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)

Comment: When I asked this same question at Gardening and Landscaping, I was told to leave a message in the site's main chat room. Almost every day, a high rep user or moderator comes through, or you can "ping" one. If they agree, they'll make the edit. I finally have enough rep there now (the threshold is only 1,000) to help others, which I love to do!  This is a bigger site, and I don't know if it works the same way, so I'm not advocating it, just telling you my experience at GL.

Comment: *If there are only code tags and backticks  that are needed in the question* then you can consider adding a comment explaining the OP the need of them, until you get your edit applies immediately privilege.  Optionally, direct them to site's formatting help page.

Answer (score 6):

If the changes to be made are so minor that you can't find anything else to change, then just move on.

In my experience, there is rarely a post that needs edits where there is not more than six characters to fix. Even so, there are *plenty* of other posts that are in serious need of editing.

Once you get to 2000 reputation you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Yes. 2k rep have inline editing too.